# Call a function in another javascript function synchronously

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I am trying to call `checkLoginStatus` function in `getUserAlbum` function, in the `getUserAlbum` I am catching the response return by `checkLoginStatus` and on behalf of that response I need to work under the `getUserAlbum` function.

But the problem is this `getUserAlbum` function does not wait for the response and execute the next line that I do not want.

Here is my functions:

```
   var accessToken = '';

   checkLoginStatus = function () {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                console.log(accessToken + ' => in check login status');
                return accessToken;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    getUserAlbum = function () {
        var token = checkLoginStatus();
        console.log(token + ' => in get album function'); // it log undefined here that is why else part executes.
        if(token) {
            FB.api(
                "/me/albums/", {'accessToken': token},
                function (response) {
                  if (response && !response.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                  }
                }
            );
        } else {
            alert("You are not logged in");
        }
    }
```

Someone can please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `FB.getLoginStatus` is asynchronous...Use `callbacks`

Comment: can you please tell me how to use callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `FB.getLoginStatus` is asynchronous...Use `callbacks` as `response` from `FB` api will be asynchronous. You can not be certain when will it be received.

Your function is executed and control is returned before the `response` is received hence it will be `undefined`.

In `callbacks`, you pass `function` as argument will will be executed later in the program when needed.

```js
var accessToken = '';
var checkLoginStatus = function(callback) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      callback(accessToken);
    } else {
      callback(false);
    }
  });
}
var getUserAlbum = function() {
  checkLoginStatus(function(token) {
    console.log(token + ' => in get album function'); // it log undefined here that is why else part executes.
    if (token) {
      FB.api(
        "/me/albums/", {
          'accessToken': token
        },
        function(response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      alert("You are not logged in");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, and now I understand that what was the issue. Thanks for the explanation.